# Android is blacklisting our location

Tags: android, gps

We have created a LocationListener in our application. Sometimes, the phone will go into a "GPS Gap" and simply stop reporting location data. We have watched for a while and the only thing that seems to move it from this state is rebooting the phone.

I hooked them up to get the logs off and found this:

```
02-18 13:35:43.671   703   948 I LocationManagerService: handleLocationChanged for android.uid.system:1000, Provider: passive
02-18 13:35:43.671   703   948 I LocationManagerService: handleLocationChanged for com.google.uid.shared:10040, Provider: passive
02-18 13:35:43.671   703   948 I LocationManagerService: handleLocationChanged for com.google.uid.shared:10040, Provider: passive
02-18 13:35:43.671   703   948 D LocationManagerService: dropping location (blacklisted): com.google.android.apps.maps matches com.google.
```

Looking at the mentioned source files, it simply checks a blacklist that it creates and evidently doesn't report the point if it's in the blacklist.

Looking at the code and the above it looks like its blocking location data for anything com.google, but I don't know why.

I searched and found nothing on this and was hoping for some help.

Comment: Are you developing this app from inside the White House? or from some military base somewhere? Here is that string inside the source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.3_r2.1/services/java/com/android/server/location/LocationBlacklist.java However, it doesn't talk about the underlying purpose of that blacklist, so I am as stumped as you are.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I could tell you about the super secret spy app that we're writing, but then I'd have to shoot you.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Sorry, in case you're serious, no, I know of no reason why this space would be blacklisted. Also, we have a number of phones at this location and the blacklist only applies to an occasional phone, so it's local to the phone and not some universal blacklist.

Comment: Well, I did read your bio. Your industry is the only one that is allowed to use cell phone jammers in the US. So I wasn't sure about the blacklist. Is the problem limited to specific brand of phone?

Comment: Right now, we only use Motorola RAZR M. We are looking for new devices, so that's the only one we tested on.

Comment: There seem to be some long-standing location and geocoding issues with 4.0.x and possibly 4.1.x.  I would see if you have the same problem on 4.2+, and if not, don't waste any more time on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should plug your phone into an IDE and reboot it while watching the logical for any changes that may be contributing to the location ban. I think the likely reason is that your device identifier takes some time to register with the cell phone antenna and that is what's causing the reboot to appear temporarily to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Location blacklists and whitelists are stored in the `Settings.Secure` values `locationPackagePrefixBlacklist` and `locationPackagePrefixWhitelist`, respectively. These values contain comma separated package name prefixes. `LocationBlacklist.isBlackListed()` first checks the blacklist for a match and then checks the whitelist for an exception. `LocationBlacklist` registers a `ContentObserver` so any changes to the settings values take affect immediately.

As of Android 5.1, the lists are consulted by `getLastLocation()` and `handleLocationChangedLocked()` of `LocationManagerService`, as well as `updateFences()` of `GeofenceManager`. These simply return null  or exit silently if the app's prefix or full name is blacklisted. All other location APIs are unaffected.

Since you are observing a run-time change in the blacklist, there must be a system process adding `com.google` to the `Settings.Secure` value sometime after boot. If you can't identify that, then perhaps manually changing the value via sqlite3 command line would restore updates to your app. It might get changed back at some point, but identification of the culprit could be easier than having to wait for a reboot every time. You might also try adding `com.google.android.apps.maps` to the whitelist exceptions.

As far as the root cause of your problem, my wild guess is that the blacklisting is being done by some part of Gapps on your device. Perhaps it thinks it's running inside an emulator or VM? Are you running a custom ROM?